# Get other Players instantiated gameobjects Unity Photon

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development, photon

I am trying to access the Location of all the other Players who are connected to the same room. I first thought about getting the already instantiated gameobject but they all had the same name so that won't work. I wan't to to a Terrain Generator but when every Player generates Terrain its all messed up into each other. So i thought maybe just the first player has to generate the Terrain for himself and all other players to, but i now don't know how to get the other players positions. Therefore i can't check who is the first Player. So my second Question is: **Is there maybe an other way to let only one generate the Terrain for all?**

When i used the name to access my player i only got the player who i was already playing, i tried something where i send the player coordinates, but that only gives the coordinates when the photonView.isMine isnt True.

This is my Code so far this script is on the Player Prefab which gets instantiated when a player joins.

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Cinemachine;



public class NetworkPlayer : Photon.MonoBehaviour
{
    private bool generatingTerrain;
    private Vector3 correctPlayerPos;
    private Quaternion correctPlayerRot;
    private GameObject LevelGenerator;
    private GameObject Player;
    private float pos;
    

    Rigidbody2D rb;
    void Start()
    {
        LevelGenerator = GameObject.Find("LevelGenerator");
        generatingTerrain = LevelGenerator.transform.Find("Level Generator");
        Debug.Log(generatingTerrain);
        if (photonView.isMine)
        {
            rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
            rb.simulated = true;
            GetComponent<PlayerController>().enabled = true;
        }
    }

    void Update()
    {
        //Debug.Log(generatingTerrain);
        if (!photonView.isMine)
        {
            transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, this.correctPlayerPos, Time.deltaTime * 5);
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(transform.rotation, this.correctPlayerRot, Time.deltaTime * 5);
            Destroy(rb);
            Debug.Log("Transform Position on !isMine: " + transform.position.x.ToString());
            pos = transform.position.x;

        }

        Player = GameObject.Find("Player_1(Clone)");
        if (photonView.isMine)
        {
            Debug.Log("photonView.isMine: " + transform.position.x.ToString());
            Debug.Log("pos " + pos.ToString());
        }


    }
    void OnPhotonSerializeView(PhotonStream stream, PhotonMessageInfo info)
    {
        if (stream.isWriting)
        {
            // We own this player: send the others our data
            stream.SendNext(transform.position);
            stream.SendNext(transform.rotation);

        }
        else
        {
            // Network player, receive data
            this.correctPlayerPos = (Vector3)stream.ReceiveNext();
            this.correctPlayerRot = (Quaternion)stream.ReceiveNext();
        }
    }
}
```

Maybe i am just failing to see something, this is my first time working with unity and photon so i am really new to this topic.

If you need something just write me, i am sorry if something here is missing
Hope to get help soon :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my exact problem:

```cs
GameObject[] players = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Player");
        foreach (GameObject p in players) 
            {
            Debug.Log(p.transform.position);
            }
```

This lists every Gameobject which got the Player Tag and puts them into an Array, then you can access every of them to check that its not your own position you can just do:

```cs
if (p.position != gameobject.transform.position) {
    //Do here what you want to do with every Player who isnt you
}
```

I found the solution [here](https://forum.photonengine.com/discussion/13674/how-to-know-which-photonview-is-the-masterclient)

Answer (score 0):

As far as getting the other players position you do it correctly, by looking at if the photonView is not mine.

I am not entirely sure what you are trying to do with the terrain. Right now you are trying to generate terrain on all players in the game which will make each player object in the game generate the terrain, which will probably cause chaos.

If you want to have procedurally generated terrain I would suggest doing it with a seed and then share the seed amongst all players. The terrain generation should then only be done if photonView.isMine.
If you want to change terrain, e.g. destroy or move blocks, then you need to sync this over the network , most likely with with Events or RPC calls.

Comment: Hey, thanks for reply

I never thought about the seed thing but it seems very smart to me, so i don't have to send every new terrain platform over the network just the seed and every player generates the same terrain for himself, my next questions would be then how do i share the seed? I have looked how to share Variables over Network but im not sure how it works, and what i need to do

Comment: You don't have to send it over the network, you can add it to the room property when creating the room. Then everyone can who is in the room can access it via PhotonNetwork.CurrentRoom.CustomProperties["seed"].

Comment: Thats very good because then all players will get the seed even when the original masterclient disconnects...

Comment: Hey bro, i ve tried to implement this one and i haven't found any docs which show me how do i set a custom property, maybe you could help me out....

Comment: There is lots of information out there, Google is your friend. But for the sake of it: ExitGames.Client.Photon.Hashtable roomProperties = PhotonNetwork.CurrentRoom.CustomProperties;
            roomProperties["seed"] = "yourSeed";
            PhotonNetwork.CurrentRoom.SetCustomProperties(roomProperties);

Comment: Yes i searched further and further and discovered the thing with the hastables i already got it running now.. But thx for helping out